# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. (Python rocketcea wrapper for NASA Fortran CEA)

Tags: python, dll, installation, fortran, wrapper

I am trying to use the [rocketcea](https://github.com/sonofeft/RocketCEA) (installed via pip rather than cloning the git) wrapper for NASA's CEA code, but I recieve the following error in the title when I try to run their example code:

```py
#example code
from rocketcea.cea_obj import CEA_Obj
C = CEA_Obj( oxName='LOX', fuelName='LH2')
for mr in range(2,9):
    print(mr, C.get_Isp(Pc=100.0, MR=mr, eps=40.0) )
```

Resulting error (Python 3.7 launched from the PyCharm IDE):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/George/Documents/SpaceportTXV/cea test/cea import.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rocketcea.cea_obj import CEA_Obj
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rocketcea\cea_obj.py", line 51, in <module>
    import rocketcea.py_cea as py_cea
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using the MinGW GCC compiler suite, and I have added both bin and lib to my PATH as rocketcea [recommends](https://rocketcea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#running-rocketcea) to resolve the issue.

My PATH:

```
C:\Users\George>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\mingw\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\mingw\mingw64\lib;
```

If it helps, [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mA4h.png) to what my rocketcea folder contains.

If anyone has any insight as to why I am having this error, I would greatly appreciate it. I can also add any additional information that may be helpful

Comment: This is really your *%PATH%* env var? Where is *System32* (or other standard paths where *.dll*s reside)? I'd suggest to also paste the outputs from `echo %PATH%`, and how do you launch *Python*. (and also `${PATH_TO_YOUR}python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)")`. Where are you launching from  (*cmd*, other terminal)?

Comment: Sometimes DLL errors are caused by missing dependent DLLs. Error messages from interpreted languages are usually terrible at telling you this. Download [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) and have it analyze your DLL. Look specifically for missing dependencies, don't get caught up in some of the other things it reports.

Comment: Please add the missing info: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You mentioned using *MinGW32* build tool suite. You are building the package (parts) with it. What *Python* are you using?

Comment: I have changed the information I added regarding PATH and Python version. I'm not very familiar with DLLs since I only code for scientific purposes, so I am unsure of what to do with Dependency Walker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if an alternative solution will have been found by now, but after struggling for hours on end with this, I found a way to make the error message go away. This was done òn Windows 10 with an Anaconda3 install running Python 3.6.8 x64, but the core idea is that in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rocketcea`, one can navigate to `..\rocketcea\.libs`, where a .dll file resides. I added the path to this .libs folder to my Path variable, and on calling the test code again, it ran.

I hope this helps.

As a side note, I also added the path to the `python3.dll` file in my python install folder to the Path variable, but I suspect the rocketcea specific .dll was the true key.