# How can I find missing module for RocketCEA?

Tags: python, dll, importerror

I tried installing RocketCEA as described here https://rocketcea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#test-the-install.

However, every time I try to run the following command in cmd

```
python -c "from rocketcea.cea_obj import CEA_Obj; C=CEA_Obj(oxName='LOX', fuelName='LH2'); print(C.get_Isp())"
```

I get the following message:

```
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mirel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rocketcea\cea_obj.py", line 51, in <module>
    import rocketcea.py_cea as py_cea
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does someone know how to fix this?
I would be very grateful!

Comment: Have you verified that the installation was successful? How?

Comment: Verifying whether the installation is successful is the point of the above, at least this is what they say here: https://rocketcea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#test-the-install. So I guess mine was not, but I do not understand what I did wrong, as I followed the steps before 1:1.

Comment: Right, so now you'll need to review logs of each preceding step to determine which one did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've already found [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. (Python rocketcea wrapper for NASA Fortran CEA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633781/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-python-r), but I had the same issue and was able to solve it through the answer provided by JOlisT - adding `...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rocketcea\ .libs` to my `PATH`, which can be done by editing system environment variables if using Windows.

If not that, you may want to double check that whichever compiler you have is both functioning and accessible through python by compiling a "Hello world" Fortran code you can write with Notepad++.